# Verificar se um item de uma ListBox foi selecionado

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, userform, listbox, excel-vba

Tenho uma lista `ListBox1` q uma caixa de seleção `ChckBox1` em um UserForm. Quero ativar ou inativar a caixa de seleção (`CheckBox1.Enabled = True/False` se algum item da lista estiver selecionado.

A caixa de seleção está desativada inicialmente, mas se algo for selecionado, quero que ela seja habilitada para marcação.

No presente momento estou usando um loop para validação, mas gostaria de saber se há uma maneira mais direta, sem ter que analizar item a item.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

    Dim s As Boolean: s = False
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            s = True
            Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    CheckBox1.Enabled = s

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
Dim s As Boolean: s = False

If ListBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
   s = True
End If

CheckBox1.Enable = s
```